# Not reloading listview in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

In my application, I'm using ListView and has uneven rows.I have Editor inside List view item and I want to grow editor and List item(Cell) according to the text inside Editor. In my case Editor growing onto the next List item. If I reload list view(doing setting ItemSource nil and setting item source to list) every List item(cell adjusted height according to the text inside the editor) looking good.
How to reload ListView without setting Item source to nil.